# started+ verb vs. verb

Tags: grammar

Why most of the time some of the verbs(both infinitives and gerunds) are prefixed with the word started, is it a stylistic matter or does it give a better flow to the statement? Cant we use the base form of the verb without the word start? For example:

> Recently in our school, they started teaching/to teach computer philosophy.

Comment: It would be helpful if the OP could rewrite his example sentence to align it with the question title. At present the example sentence seems to focus on whether we follow *start* with the gerund or the infinitive, but I don't think that is what is being asked here.

Comment: I am closing this as NARQ because a) *obviously* you can say "teach" rather than "start teaching", just like you can say "jump" instead of "stop jumping" or "car" instead of "red car", b) *obviously* you will be changing the meaning if you do so, and c) *obviously* the part about "most of the time" is a false premise. Infinitives and gerunds in English are *not* "prefixed" with "started" most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can use the verb without "started", but you'd have to adjust it and you'll lose some information.

> Recently at* our school, they teach computer philosophy.

This sentence doesn't make sense because "recently" hangs there without anything to give it context. So you'd have to change it to:

> At* our school, they teach computer philosophy.

Now the sentence makes sense, but now you've lost the information that the teaching of this course has begun only *recently*. Even if you left out "recently", the word would be implied, as in:

> They started teaching computer philosophy at* our school.

It's information about when something started (you could also say "they began to teach..."). So it's not just a matter of style or flow, it gives the sentence temporal context.

*Edit: Unrelated to your question, but I'd say that "*at* our school" should be used instead of "*in* our school" for this example.

Comment: -1 I don't see how this addresses OP's question (difference between *teaching* and *to teach*) at all.

Comment: I actually think OP *is* asking about the use of the word *started* and not about infinitive vs gerund.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The question's title is "started + verb vs. verb", not "teaching vs. to teach" (those were just two options in the example sentence). Also, Noah clearly asks why verbs are prefixed with "started" and whether we can't just use the verb form without "started". I'm pretty sure I'm _not_ the one misunderstanding the question here, perhaps you should read it again ;-)

Comment: Yes okay - I guess you're right. But in that case I agree with RegDwight that the actual question as posed doesn't make much sense anyway. Though it *has* prompted me to wonder why *started/ceased* don't seem to behave the same as *commenced/stopped*. I'll have to think about that one, and if I can't figure it out, maybe I'll post a question about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's purely a matter of style whether you use the gerund *(teaching)* or the infinitive *(to teach)* after "started" - neither conveys any subtle nuance not shared by the other.

For OP's particular choice of verb, it so happens *"started teaching"* [occurs more often](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=started%20teaching,started%20to%20teach&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), but as [this chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=started%20arguing,started%20to%20argue&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for *argue* shows, both verb forms can be equally common.

[image]

*But* - this "gerund/infinitive equality" doesn't apply to *all* verbs...

> Our school **ceased/began** teaching/to teach Latin last year. *(both are okay)*
>
> Our school **stopped/commenced** teaching/*to teach Latin last year. *(the infinitive is **not** okay here)*

(As of right now, I can't actually say why this difference arises with certain auxiliary verbs.)

Comment: I believe this is a totally correct answer to the wrong question :)  The OP is asking why "started" is needed - teaching vs to teach is beside the point.

Answer (score 0):

It's a verb tense issue.  You could use "recently + teach" in simple past tense:

> Recently they *taught* computer philosophy at my school.

But this doesn't convey your intent.  You're not talking about a single class that happened in the past.  You're talking about the start of an ongoing action.   That leads you to the progressive tense:

> Recently they *started teaching* computer philosophy at my school.

Here is [a source](http://en.allexperts.com/q/General-Writing-Grammar-680/start-sth-vs-start.htm) that tries to explain it further.