# "... disheartened and humbled as we are,..."?

Tags: sentence, redundancy

I wonder if we need ***as we are*** in this sentence.

> In our present state, disheartened by failures and humbled by our weaknesses ***as we are***, it is impossible to win this battle.

The presence of ***In our present state*** makes ***as we are*** redundant, but as I was writing the sentence, it just sounded natural to add *as we are*, as if I heard a kind of refrain in my mind. When I realised the problem, I tried removing it:

> In our present state, disheartened by failures and humbled by our weaknesses, it is impossible to win this battle.

Is not the second sentence a bit dry? Shall I leave "as we are" in, or will it come across as disturbingly redundant?

Edit: There were some good answers but in the form of comments, so I cannot resolve the question by accepting them.

Comment: First, look at https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123870/encompassed-as-i-am-by-frost-and-snow-what-does-the-as-mean and then please say if you still need our help.

Comment: @Anton: My question is a bit more particular. I am asking if we can have _in our present state_ and _as we are_ in the same sentence. Is this a wrong question to ask?

Comment: It's in a literary style, emphasising _our sorry state_. A redundancy? _Of course_ (Only a _real_ pedant would complain of the arguably misplaced modifier.) Incorrect? _Only arguably so on style grounds_. Poor style, then? _I **prefer** the original, especially if it's period writing. It both lends to the historic feel, and avoids the slight jarringness of the twinning of the clinical 'In our present state it is impossible to win this battle' with non-clinical 'disheartened' and 'humbled'._ But off-topic on ELU, as a request for style advice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Oh, is there a site for style advice then? I searched "style" but with no results. Thank you for your comment, I tend to feel the same way.

Comment: Writing.SE. 'Redundancy is always wrong' as a mantra is neither fine nor dandy, as a bit of [digging and delving in the archives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/390026/why-is-redundant-language-bad)  will uncover. //// Hm; that 'complain of' should have been 'complain about'. Or are misplaced modifiers an illness?

Comment: "complain of" vs "complain about"... I hadn't noticed, thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are literary precedents for this construction that reinforce my own experience of its acceptable use, as in your example.

> "*Conscious as I am, sir, of the disadvantage of making such a declaration to you, under such circumstances, I have come here, because ...*"
>
> "*Enthusiastic as we are in the noble cause to which we have devoted ourselves, we should* ..."
>
> [Pickwick Papers](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/580/580-h/580-h.htm)

> *"But the fact is, that being, as I am, to inherit this estate*"
>
> *"Intimate as you are, you must know how it is to be done."*
>
> [Pride and Prejudice](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1342/1342-h/1342-h.htm)

The phrase seems to emphasise the state of the person speaking: *now*; *at this moment*; *in particular relation to the surrounding circumstances, be they past or future*.

Writing *as I am* from a literary perspective, I suggest that despite a spurious redundancy the phrase is useful and acceptable.

Comment: The best example of literary redundancy is the first, and it might do the trick to convince me, together with EdwinA's comment :) . The others are not really examples of redundancy, but of the use of _as one is_. However, I am grateful for all of them, I love examples of this kind. I am a bit intrigued by the punctuation of the third sentence you gave. Are you sure that the commas are in their right place?

Comment: It was a searching question. I too see a lot of commas but am not the person to dispute Miss Austen's style. My search was limited to a quick check on precedent for my own experience and could never be exhaustive.

Comment: Pretty amazing, I must say. I wonder what she was trying to convey through the positions of the commas... I am not questioning her style, just making sure that this is how she wanted it.

Comment: @Anton, Aren't all of your examples (which I enjoyed) distinguishable from the one given by the OP in that, in your examples, you can't remove "*as I am*" without destroying the sentence? That is, "*as I am*" is necessary to make the sentence understandable.

Comment: @JimSimson  agree to some extent. I felt that they all could be stated more simply with a plain meaning that nevertheless lacked the overtones of the removed construction.

Comment: @Anton, I see, point taken. Thank you.

Comment: Yes; 'Intimate, you must know how it is to be done' is grammatically fine, but this adjective needs a marker of reciprocity ('you' can only be 2nd person _plural_), and absolutes need to be chosen carefully in any case. 'Disconsolate, he slumped in the armchair' / ??'Sad, he slumped in the armchair'.

Answer (score 0):

fav,

My own two cents here: I would absolutely ditch the, "as we are". I don't read your second sentence as dry at all, I see it as a concise, pithy statement. In your first sentence, "as we are" is not only redundant but as a first-time reader of the sentence, it's jarring and threw me off. I'll be interested to see if others feel differently.